# Auto-login on desktop no working method found yet

Tags: raspbian, gui, raspi-config, lxde, login

I need a Raspberry PI to login on boot and execute a bunch of scripts.
The bunch of scripts part is working fine.

For the auto-login, it isn't as cooperative.
I work on a RPI that has had quite some modifications yet.
It is on Raspbian installed with NOOBS.
As I started working on it, it already started with a login GUI, getting me to the desktop.

Here is what I tried so far to skip the login screen :

```
sudo raspi-config
```

And desktop log in as user 'pi' at the graphical desktop.
Reboot to see the changes.. Nothing.

Then I tried the several /etc/inittab lines :

```
1:2345:respawn:/bin/login -f pi tty1 </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1
1:2345:respawn:/bin/login -f pi tty1 / dev/tty1 2>&1
```

And the variants with different space placements.
I forgot some unfortunately.

Finally, I tried putting these in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

```
autologin-user=identifiant
autologin-user-timeout=0
pam-service=lightdm-autologin
```

Nothing worked. So I'm starting to lose hope. I can't know what has been done before on this RPI to get it not working.

If you have any idea where to search, or any alternative solution, I'll take it.

Thanks.

Comment: Your not alone, I am dealing with the same issue.

Comment: I haven't looked in a while, but last time I checked Raspian defaulted to LXDE, so googling "LXDE auto login" should point you in the right direction. The gist is that you have to edit the configuration file for LXDM, but the exact edits (and the location of the file) depend on the distribution and LXDE version. Unfortunately all of my Pis are headless right now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my problem.

It might help some lost souls.

My RPI turned out to use XDM as its default display manager.
And it appears that XDM doesn't allow at all autologin.

So what I did :

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

And then, the raspi-config stuff worked without any problem.

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar problem and resolved it using following

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lxsession
```

I got a hint about this from .xsession-errors file.
The error in this file was

`/usr/bin/x-session-manager: 33: exec: /usr/bin/lxsession: not found`

Comment: You're my hero! This worked, and is the only place I found this suggestion.

Comment: @kregus, glad it worked for you..!

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem and found that commenting out the following line from `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` fixed the issue:

Before:

```
autologin-session=LXDE-pi-x
```

After:

```
# autologin-session=LXDE-pi-x
```